# Blank view when running in non 64 bit simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm presenting a view controller from story board, when I run in 64 bit and on my iPad air, it's running fine but in the regular simulator I can't see it. I see a blank view presented instead of my actual view controller..

is there a setting I'm possibly missing on storyboard? I'm not getting any errors.

```
    ViewController *destination = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoard_iPad" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
[self presentViewController:destination animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Nothing here would behave any differently in 64 or 32-bit mode.  It's going to probably be something in the ViewController code itself.

Comment: The weird thing is it's not even getting to my viewcontroller methods, none of the break points are hit.

Comment: Try a clean build and reset simulator contents and settings.

Comment: Weird, that's the first thing I did with no luck, but now I did it again just now and it worked....Thanks, would have kept chasing a bug..